# Virtualbox sometimes freezes when powering off a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 in Virtualbox under a Linux Mint 13 host, and I noticed that powering off the machine (instead of shutting it down) took more than 42 minutes. I chose to power off the virtual machine because it had become totally unresponsive. The progress bar on the "powering off" notification is stuck at around 50%. What is the usual cause of this problem (if any is known)?

(I'll admit that I didn't look at any of the log files before posting this question - I'll try to add this information as soon as possible. The log files may contain relevant information, but I haven't yet found the relevant files.)

Recently, on September 1, 2013, I encountered a very similar problem on a Windows 8 host machine with a Linux Mint guest machine. Now it's stuck at 14% instead of 50%, and the estimated time remaining is more than 2 hours.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I didn't select the "shut down" option in Virtualbox - I selected the "power off" option. I have never encountered an error like this before - I expected the "power off" option to be much faster than the "shut down" option.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Also, do you know where the log files are likely to be stored (in case of an unusual error like this one?)

Comment: Unless Linux Mint is completely different than any other distribution, it will store log files in `/var/log` directory.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Also, is it possible to "watch the shutdown process" even when the virtual machine is unresponsive? I don't understand this part entirely.

Comment: I'm with Michael on this one.  Have you looked at any log files?

Comment: Have a look at the log files on the host under /var/log

Comment: @MattH Which log files are likely to contain relevant information?

Comment: @MattH Also, why is this question getting lots of downvotes? Is it because I didn't look at the log files before posting it (which didn't even occur to me at the time?) Or does the question simply show a lack of research (because the answer is obvious to everyone except me?)

Comment: OK, I was mistaken... ["Power off" is like pulling the virtual power cord.](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp8361104) It should go away pretty much immediately, doing whatever damage to your virtual guest's filesystem that yanking the power cord would do to a physical machine. You definitely have a weird problem here.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - This sounds like a problem with the HDD in the sense, it takes forever, to save the virtual machine.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you mean the physical HDD, or the virtual HDD?

Comment: @AndersonGreen - The storage device where the virtual machine is located on.

Answer (score -3):

The time taken to shutdown may be due to less ram available for the PC to work. Which means if u have windows 7 64 bit and in the virtual machine you use Ubuntu 64 bit then the windows requires 2GB ram and ubuntu requires 1GB and in your PC you have installed 2 GB ram then  there is a chance of slow response of the virtual machine.

Comment: Is the "power off" option likely to be faster than the "shut down" option? I used the "power off" option, not the "shut down" option.

Comment: Shut down option takes comparatively more time than the power off. I think so power off option must he used

Comment: @SiddharthWarrier - Why do you talk about Windows when the author is using a Linux host?  Where do you get the memory values from, this information was supplied, you just pulling this out of thin air?